# Looking for the OpenType font or installable version of LaTeX mathematical fonts for Mac

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I'm currently using `\mathcal{*}` in some of my equations. How can I recreate the same font in illustrations? I use Affinity Designer for illustrations as I'm not familiar with `tikz`.

I'm unable to locate the OpenType font or an installable version of LaTeX mathematical fonts. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: you can use latin modern math opentype font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure that's going to help if @PPR needs fonts that match the default `\mathcal`. The opentype version of Latin Modern Math does have mathematical script letters in the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block but they look different. You might use `cmsy10.ttf` from [the Bakoma collection here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf) maybe.

Comment: Thanks, @frabjous. `cmsy10.ttf` works for me. Thanks for your help.